# Is it possible to drop a specific stash from the stash list in git?

Tags: git, github

With git stash list, I see the list of stashes, Is it possible to drop a stash from somewhere in the middle of the stash list and not from the top.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: the question you marked this as a dupe of asks something very different.

Comment: @JohnZwinck The accepted answer in that question says the same thing which your answer says.  I would prefer that indexed duplicate link over this question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: There is no accepted answer in that question, and the most upvoted answer does not mention `drop` at all.

Comment: I have added a more appropriate duplicate, though the OP should be able to figure out using either link.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: That ("pop specific stash in 1.8.3") is also not a duplicate question, because it is about a version incompatibility with the way stashes are named (and how shell escaping works) in an old version of Git.  I think you are choosing dupes based on keywords in the answers, not based on what the questions are about.

Comment: I agree with @JohnZwinck, this shouldn't be marked as duplicate, it is related but not duplicate.

Comment: I agree that the two previous dupes weren't ideal. I've just edited the list of dupes and added a better top duplicate, removed the "pop specific stash" duplicate, and left the "name and retrieve stashes" duplicate since knowing how to refer to stashes is important. This is still a duplicate (and covered in the documentation for `git stash`) and I'm not voting to re-open.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sure, `git stash --help` says:

```
   git stash drop [-q|--quiet] [<stash>]
```

So you can specify a stash to drop (with the default being the most recent stash).  For example:

```
git stash drop stash@{5}
```

`stash@{5}` is the sequential label as shown in `git stash list`.  Note it is not stable over time--once you drop stash 5, stash 6 will then be called stash 5.

Comment: Depending on recent your `git` version is, you can use `git stash drop 5` as well.